# How to spin up 'n' instances of an app / container with pre-loaded memory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-ecs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Background:
I have a language processing java app that requires about 16MB memory and takes about 40 seconds to initialise resources into that memory before exposing a webservice. I am new to containers and related technologies so apologies if my question is obvious...

Objective:
I want to make available several hundred instances of my app on-demand and in a pre-loaded/ pre-configured state. (eg I could make a call to AWS to stand-up 'n' instances of my app and they would be ready in <10seconds.)

Question:
I'm anticipating that I 'may' be able to create a docker image of the app, initialise it and pause hence be able to clone that on demand and 'un-pause' ? Could you advise whether what I am looking to do is possible and if so, how you would approach it.

AWS is my platform of choice so any AWS flavoured specifics would be super helpful.

Comment: AWS doesn't have the ability to pause an instance and remember its state. You will have to add this feature to your product. Once your product is able to load quickly, there are many ways to create many instances and it really depends on  your needs.

Comment: @kichik's comment also applies to Docker: a Docker image is a filesystem image only and doesn't contain any running processes or in-memory state.

Comment: thanks kichik and david-maze, these are helpful clarifications !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd split your question in two, if you don't mind:
1. Spinning up N containers (or, more likely, scale on demand)
2. Preloading memory.

#1 is Kubernetes's bread and butter and you can find a ton of resources about it online, so allow me to focus on #2.

The real problem is that you're too focused on a possible solution to see the bigger picture:
You want to "preload memory" in order to speed up launch time (well, what do you think Java is doing in those 40s that the magick memory preloader wouldn't?).

A different approach would be to launch the container, let Java eat up resources for 40s, but not make that container available to the world during that time.
Kubernetes provides tools to achieve exactly that, see here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful to focus on (2).
I am anticipating that in the 40s, Java is busy unpacking resources and processing them before storing some data structures in memory, hence, I wonder if there may be a way of loading the filled mem straight from a cache or disk (a bit like pausing a VM) - it's quicker to unpause than to re-start an operating system from scratch and re-open all of the applications ?

Comment: That question has nothing to do with Kubernetes, that's about Java object (de)serialization, and I'm afraid I can't help you there. I would suggest googling the term "premature optimization". From a Kubernetes standpoint, there's a timeframe where the container cannot serve requests, and I explained how to deal with that in my answer. You really shouldn't care if it takes 40 seconds or 10 seconds, I don't really see the point (it doesn't cost much more in cloud resources, it's still quick enough to auto-scale to meet real-world demands, and so forth).